# What is the difference between a 0 Ohm Resistor and a piece of wire?

Tags: resistors

As I was browsing through parts listings for a 3D printer project, I stumbled upon a resistor listed as "0 Ohm". Fittingly, it had a single band in the center: a black band. Because of \$U_t=R_tI_t\$, this piece immediately felt rather silly to me, as it wouldn't change the outcome of a series after Kirchhoff (\$R_t=\sum R_i\$) and would be a short in a parallel design: \$U_t=U_1 \& R_1=0\Omega \rightarrow I_1=\infty\$

What difference does this *nill* resistor have to just a piece of wire put in its place? Is there a special application where such a piece is used or is it just some kind of novelty?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[image]

Zero-ohm resistors have several benefits over a simple bit of cable:

- They can be used as a wire link and can be inserted automatically by PCB assembly robots. They come on a reel so no additional setup is required.
- They can be used where a resistor may be or was used in certain design variations.
- They can be used as test points.
- They are often seen on single-sided PCBs to provide a jumper across some tracks to avoid impossible or very long alternate routes.

Wikipedia's [Zero-ohm link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-ohm_link) has an interesting addition:

> The resistance is only approximately zero; only a maximum (typically 10–50 mΩ) is specified.[2] A percentage tolerance would not make sense, as it would be specified as a percentage of the ideal value of zero ohms (which would always be zero), so it is not specified.

Comment: They can be used to program options on a PCB.

Comment: They are mandatory for mil-spec and NASA standards which do not allow bare 'jumpers' under any conditions. On multi-layer boards jumpers would be considered a fix for a routing mistake, but a zero ohm resistor is acceptable.

Comment: @Sparky256 Short bare jumpers are allowed by NASA, AFAUI.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that a length of wire is *also* not actually 0 Ω. A comparison of the resistance for a typical wire with a length similar to the zero-ohm resistor would be a nice enhancement. (But for reference, +1 regardless.)

Comment: I also use them so that I can optionnaly change its value later (to set an RC filter / to limit noise propagation / ...).