# Why 0R used in voltage lines in series?

Tags: voltage

I have a question about eval board schematics of STMP1.

I noticed that zero ohm resistors were used in the PMIC reference circuit.

Why these resistors used in series to the power lines? Need I them really?

[image]

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/385940/what-is-the-difference-between-a-0-ohm-resistor-and-a-piece-of-wire/385941#385941.

Comment: It saves taking a scalpel to the PCB when working on it, debugging, or measuring current consumption of some sub-unit.

Comment: Do you need them? Hmm; will the device work if they are not iinstalled? ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why these resistors used as series to the power lines? Need them
>   really?

If you have multiple circuits teeing off the same power rail and the overall circuit is quite complex, there is a good reason for putting zero ohm links in series with the individual power feeds and that reason becomes apparent when fault finding.

If one circuit is dragging the whole power rail down (due to a shorted sub-circuit somewhere), having zero ohm links helps to track down the fault because they are easily removable, easily replaceable and cheap.

Personally if the individual load current requirements are moderate and you could bear the cost of a 0.1 ohm resistor (instead of zero ohms) you could probably identify the rogue sub-circuit using a DVM across each zero ohm link. Bear also in mind that zero ohm links might be sufficiently "resistive" to facilitate this nicety.

The [Vishay CRCW zero ohm link](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2310790.pdf?_ga=2.122029323.1648955040.1579702241-100628718.1565709467&_gac=1.12183040.1579170417.EAIaIQobChMI94CX2rHe4AIVRofVCh3YTg-hEAAYASAAEgI-bPD_BwE) has a maximum resistance of 0.02 ohms so I suspect it could be somewhat relied upon to be about 0.01 ohms. 2 amp through 0.01 ohms is a volt drop of 20 mV and very easily seen on a modern DVM.

Comment: Upvote but I think it's worth mentioning that these are a good idea on the first revision or two of a PCB, but can often safely be removed once the design is sufficiently validated - if saving a few cents and mm^2 per board is important.

Comment: They help diagnose faults in the field or in production so it’s probably not all that wise to remove them.

Comment: OK, fair point!

Comment: Thank you, I decided to connect a series of resistors as well :)